# Karma - Separate configuration for Debug and Release versions using grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

I have an angularJS app with unit tests using karma. Right now, my `karma.conf.js` file is configured to load the files from my `/app` folder

```
files: [
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/main-controller.js',
      'app/app.js',
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],
```

My question is: Can I add another set of configurations to run the tests on my `/dist` folder? Is there any point of doing this?

Many thanks!

Uri

Answer (score 0):

Not like an expert, but so far I know these (correct me if I am wrong):

1. Yes you can.
2. It is depent on how many tests you wanna run in once. If you want to run once per time. Settup another `karma.conf` file. If you want to run everything at once. Put all the files in the config.